# Line Chart creation using google script - Google sheet as Data source

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization, linechart

Hi Have a google sheet data whose data looks like this

```js
DATE              LSL LCL DATA UCL USL
16 - Nov - 2018     1  3   2.3   7  9
17 - Nov - 2018     1  3   3.1   7  9
18 - Nov - 2018     1  3   2.7   7  9
19 - Nov - 2018     1  3   4.9   7  9
20 - Nov - 2018     1  3   5     7  9
21 - Nov - 2018     1  3   3     7  9
22 - Nov - 2018     1  3   10    7  9
23 - Nov - 2018     1  3   7.8   7  9
24 - Nov - 2018     1  3   4.5   7  9
25 - Nov - 2018     1  3   5.4   7  9
26 - Nov - 2018     1  3   2.2   7  9
27 - Nov - 2018     1  3   4.9   7  9
28 - Nov - 2018     1  3   5.8   7  9
29 - Nov - 2018     1  3   4.9   7  9
```

I wish to develop a web script/google script to draw a line chart making use of the data from a google sheet. I dont wish to construct a data table in the app script and build the chart but rather build the chart directly by sourcing the data from the google sheet.

This is the code i developed.

**1st code - which is a .gs file - FILE NAME : Code.gs**

```js
function doGet(e) {

  return HtmlService
    .createTemplateFromFile("index")
    .evaluate()
    .setTitle("Google Spreadsheet Chart")
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

}

function getSpreadsheetData() {

  var ssID = "1WFV48PNNGw9Pvrj9dQ1vYD-kF1zvxMo_02VIbKBYicQ",
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheets()[0],
    data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  return data;

}
```

**2nd FIle - HTML. File Name: index.html**

Code as below.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="main"></div>

  <script>
    google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});

    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getSpreadsheetData);

    function getSpreadsheetData() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(drawChart).getSpreadsheetData();
}

    function drawChart(rows) {

    var options = {
    title: 'Line Chart',
    legend: 'none',
    chartArea: {
    width: '60%'
},
        
    vAxis: {
    textStyle: {
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontSize: 12
    }
   }
 };

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows, false),
    chart = new 
    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("main"));
    chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Not sure where i am getting it wrong. When i try to publish, the dashboard is empty. Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Expected outcome is

Expected Result[image]

Answer (score 1):

in the html, you have a div with id = `"main"`

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

however, in the javascript, you're trying to draw the chart in a container with id = `"curve_chart"`

```
chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById("curve_chart"));
```

the ids need to match

also, recommend cleaning up the white space in the html,
i've seen this cause problems as well

from...

```
<
div id = "main" > < /div>
```

to...

```
<div id="main"></div>
```

---

**note**: recommend using `loader.js` to load the library, vs. `jsapi`

according to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the `jsapi` loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(getSpreadsheetData);
```

Comment: hope this helps, you can find errors like this in the browser's console, F12 on most...

Comment: Dear @WhiteHat when i try to publish, its still empty/blank webpage. Not sure where i am getting it wrong.  I made all the corrections as per your suggestion

Comment: I made a change to my data source. Removed my Date column and changed to S.No's in order of 1,2,3,4.. Upon that change it worked. Why dint my code recognize date as my x-axis.

Comment: Dear @WhiteHat, any comments on this problem with having date in 1st column. Once i changed the 1st column from date to a serial number my code was able to publish.